# Which mysqli_* to use?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am reasonably new to php and am always confused which mysqli to use. Normally I would write a query like

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users`")
```

But I am always getting errors about which mysqli_something to use, whether its `mysqli_fetch_array` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` etc.

Could someone describe which to use and when or link me to a page somewhere.

Comment: Could you add the code you are using and the error you receive?

Comment: @chris85 it's not really my code related, I tend to get these errors all the time. I just need to know when to use which mysqli functions

Comment: the question's unclear then and probably opinion-based/too broad. It falls under all of those, IMHO.

Comment: I think you should go over the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and its related functions, then decide which one is best for your application.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."* - based on your *"or link me to a page somewhere"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP MySQLi = PHP MySQL Improved!

The MySQLi functions allows you to access MySQL database servers.

Note: The MySQLi extension is designed to work with MySQL version 4.1.13 or newer.

mysqli_fetch_array() is an extended version of the mysqli_fetch_row() function. In addition to storing the data in the numeric indices of the result array, the mysqli_fetch_array() function can also store the data in associative indices, using the field names of the result set as keys.You can learn more about mysqli and the functions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something like this :D

Comment: Please don't link to w3schools, link to the primary source http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Not my downvote (or upvote) here, but this IMHO is already covered in the manuals that the OP should have consulted before posting. Their question falls under quite a few reasons for a vote to close.